# Cannot move items in Linearview Android studio XML

Tags: android, xml

I have an empty activity with a form to ask questions. I've but this in a linearlayout. But now, I cannot move my elements in my Design view in Android studio. My question is, what the hell is causing this?

```
<LinearLayout android:background ="#adadad" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Censored" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSubject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/subjectactual" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/questionactual" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'd really suggest not using design view.  Android runs on xml layouts.  Learn how to edit them directly-  its faster, more accurate, and you're less likely to get surprised.

Comment: So In xml, should I use padding and margin to move stuff around? Any other tips to set position?

Comment: You shouldn't move stuff around via padding and margin (you use margin to add space between elements, and padding to increase the size of an element).  TO move stuff around like to switch two elements you'd switch their positions in the file.  If you want more than that, then you probably shouldn't be using LinearLayout but RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout and specify the position of the element via rules.